# SSM Secure reference is not supported in: AWS::EC2::Instance/Metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, metadata, aws-ssm, securestring

I am trying to use a SecureString in the meta data section of a cloud formation template but it raises the following error:

> SSM Secure reference is not supported in:
>   [AWS::EC2::Instance/Metadata/AWS::CloudFormation::Init/config/files/~/.ssh/content]

This is my code:

```
Resources:
  LinuxEC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
      config:
        files:
          ~/.ssh: 
            content: !Sub |
              '{{resolve:ssm-secure:/credentials/ansible:1}}'
            mode: "000644"
            owner: "ansible"
            group: "ansible"
```

Why does this not work? I expected secure string references to work in Cloud Formation Templates?

Comment: I ran into this too.  Opted to just get it this way - 
VAL=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name /creds/NAME/key --query 'Parameter.Value' --output text --with-decryption)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does this not work?

It does not work because `ssm-secure` is **not supported** for `AWS::EC2::Instance`. The list of supported resources is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#template-parameters-dynamic-patterns-resources) and it includes:

```
AWS::DirectoryService::MicrosoftAD
AWS::DirectoryService::SimpleAD
AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup
AWS::IAM::User
AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
AWS::OpsWorks::App
AWS::OpsWorks::Stack
AWS::OpsWorks::Stack
AWS::RDS::DBCluster
AWS::RDS::DBInstance
AWS::Redshift::Cluster
```